# How to access Angular 1.5 component property inside a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement a  simple component in Angular 1.5 I am trying to access binded(bound) properties 'compTitle'  in component mycomponentheader'.

```
var mycomponentheader = {
    ....
    bindings: {
    'comptitle': '@mycomptitle'
    },
    ....
};
```

I am  passing the attribute value [compTitle="encryptedTitle"] in html markup in the view.

```
  <mycomponentheader mycomptitle="encryptedTitle">
    <div>    
      This is displayed for component content
    </div>
  </mycomponentheader>
```

wnen i try to use the similar mechanism in directive it works.
The jsfiddle for the same is @ https://jsfiddle.net/visibleinvisibly/4n7vsas7/

i am aware of defining the template property  as a function that can be  injected with $element and $attrs (  template: function ($element, $attrs){ } in Angular 1.5) but i am looking for other methods.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [component's guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

You'll see that, by default, the bindings are bound to the `controller` and they are under `$ctrl`, instead of `this`, since `controllerAs` is used.

This being said, just access `comptitle` from `$ctrl`, as such: `$ctrl.comptitle`.

[Here is the working demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/obsypLww/)

**Note:** on the component's guide you'll see a list with the main differences between components and directives. You'll notice that some of the `mycomponentheader` properties aren't needed as they don't exist for a component. These properties include: `restrict` (it already defaults to `E`) and `replace` (which is unsupported).